# Be on someone's case

Tags: meaning

From the `Coach Carter` movie:

> I have a sister, her name's Diane. She ***was always on my case*** about
>   every little thing. Matter of fact, she still is. "Turn down that
>   radio. You eat the last piece of cake?..."

So what does it mean here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary of American Idioms](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/on+case), **on somebody's case** is an idiom and means:

> telling someone what to do or criticizing what they do

So, the meaning is:

> She always criticized me about every little thing.